# Training doesn't generalize to predict validation and test set well, how to improve generalization?

Tags: validation, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

I have built a 1D CNN regression model using features from the embedding layer by `keras`, to predict a score of some sequences.

Typical performance of my model after training is like:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the performance of predicting training data is very good but seems the performance doesn't generalize to predicting validation and testing data.

Do you have any recommendations on **how to improve validation/ test set prediction performance, possibly by trading in the prediction performance on training data?** (Is this possible?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference could be explained by overfitting (most likely). What I would say is it seems that the data before splitting into train, test and validation were not properly shuffled. Otherwise, your machine seems powerful enough to learn, given that you are satisfied from its performance in your train set, so just try to tune its hyperparameters to balance the bias-variance trade-off. The reason I cannot tell you for sure its overfitting is because your metric there is mean absolute error, so despite the fact that these curves seem very different, the difference can be explained by the fact that percentage is involved.

Ways to avoid overfitting are Dropout layers, regularization for weights etc.